# How to update json value in localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, loops, local-storage

So I have an array stringify'ed and saved in my localStorage under 'persons' key.

```
arr = [{"name":"a", "age": 1, "sport":"football"},
{"name":"b", "age": 2, "sport":"volley"},
{"name":"c", "age": 3, "sport":"basket"}];
localStorage.setItem('persons', JSON.stringify(arr));
```

When I need to update age for person with name x (lets say the input is person with name b), my approach is to get and parse my localStorage key:

```
var persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.persons);
```

Then I make a for loop to loop through the objects and find object with name b:

```
for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
   if(inputName === persons[i].name){
       persons[i].age += 2
       localStorage.setItem("persons", JSON.stringify(aCustomers[i].age));
   }
}
```

This doesnt seem to work.
I've found my match in the loop, but I dont know how to add 2 years to the age and update that value in my `localStorage.persons` without overwriting and destroying the json objects.

Comment: You're stringifying `aCustomers`. Is that what you want?

Comment: that is a mistake! should be persons!

Comment: Does that fix it, or is there another issue?

Comment: epascarello fixed it, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to set the object back again like you did originally, right now you are storing only a number, not the object.

```
var persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.persons);
for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
   if(inputName === persons[i].name){  //look for match with name
       persons[i].age += 2;  //add two
       break;  //exit loop since you found the person
   }
}
localStorage.setItem("persons", JSON.stringify(persons));  //put the object back
```

Comment: epascarello the only thing is that it adds a 2 after the age number instead of adding them together. im passing the 2 as a variable - you have any ideas?

Comment: `persons[i].age = parseInt(persons[i].age,10) + 2;`

Comment: doesnt seem to work. right enought i can see in console that person[i].age is a string, but in json its a number??

Comment: i was adding another variable (2 in this case), i did parseInt in that and then it worked.