# how to append to a local storage instead of replacing when new object is passed

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a shopping cart, when a "Add to Cart" button is pressed, It sets the object to the localStorage.

```
 const addToCartCookie = () => {

    let cartData = {
      id: product._id,
      name: product.name,
      slug: product.slug,
      productPictures: product.productPictures[0].img,
      description: "sabdsjbfjsd",
      price: product.storePrice,
      quantity: itemCount,
    };

    window.localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartData));
  };
```

If again "Add to cart" button is pressed, it replaces the previous object. I need to append each object if the product._id does not exists on the "add to cart" button call.
If product._id exists (if already product exists), I need to change the quantity(old one's quantity + new one's quantity)

Comment: You need to store an array instead (after stringifying it), and when a new product is added, you read back the array, parse it, append the new object, then store the updated array.

Comment: @close voters: this is not about updating the item, it's about how to store items to begin with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update json value in localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922349/how-to-update-json-value-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

First you need your localStorage item as an array, then check for it's existence first, create if not exists, push after parsing the array, then stringify again to save changes.

```
const itemToAdd = {
    id: product._id,
    name: product.name,
    slug: product.slug,
    productPictures: product.productPictures[0].img,
    description: "sabdsjbfjsd",
    price: product.storePrice,
    quantity: itemCount,
};

const addToCartCookie = (cartItem) => {
    const cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart');

    if(cart === null) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify([cartItem]));
    } else {
        const getCurrentCart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart');
        const currentCart = JSON.parse(getCurrentCart);

        currentCart.push(cartItem);

        window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(currentCart));
    }
};
```

use like this

```
addToCartCookie(itemToAdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach.

Make an **item_array** array.

Every time you add an item to your cart, first push it in the **item_array** and then set the complete **item_array** into the localStorage.

Before adding more items to the cart, get the **item_array** from the localStorage and push the new item into the **item_array**. Then again push this **item_array** with new item into the localStorage.

I hope you get the gist, what we're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

That is the workflow to put a new product to you localStorage array.

```js
let current = [
  {p: "abc", q: 2},
  {p: "def", q: 1},
]

let str = JSON.stringify(current);
console.log('store this string in localStorage', str)

console.log("read the string from localstorage");
let arr = JSON.parse(str)
console.log(arr)

let newProduct = {p: "hij", q: 3}
arr.push(newProduct)
console.log(arr)
```